# Button Won’t Change Image On-Click After User Goes to Home Screen

Tags: ios, image, swift, button, xcode6

I have a 5 different buttons where I want the user to be able to select one if it’s not selected, and de-select it if it already is selected, while at the same time de-selecting another button if it is selected.

normal = button’s image when not selected filled = button’s image when selected

To do this I have created an if/else statement:

@IBAction func option1ButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

```
if (option1Button.currentImage == UIImage(named: "normal")) {

    if option2Button.currentImage == UIImage(named: "filled") || option3Button.currentImage == UIImage(named: "filled") || option4Button.currentImage == UIImage(named: "filled") || option5Button.currentImage == UIImage(named: "filled") {

        option1Button.setImage(filled, forState: .Normal)

        option2Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

        option3Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

        option4Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

        option5Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

    }

    else {

        option1Button.setImage(filled, forState: .Normal)

    }

}

else {

    option1Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

}
```

}
Afterwards I made an if option1Button.currentImage == UIImage(named: "filled”) statement. Everything works exactly how I want it to, however I have one problem. Whenever the user presses the home button and then goes right back into the app, the buttons still have the “normal” image, even when clicked.

Inside the viewDidDisappear function I put the following code in hopes to fix this issue:

```
option1Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

option2Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

option3Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

option4Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)

option5Button.setImage(normal, forState: .Normal)
```

But I still have the problem occurring. I would be grateful for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change image from your button when clicked! I understand right?

For your issue I believe you can do different. I make a code for example.

First set image for state in button.

```
option1Button.setImage(normal, forState: UIControlState.Normal);
option1Button.setImage(filled, forState: UIControlState.Disabled);

option2Button.setImage(normal, forState:  UIControlState.Normal);
option2Button.setImage(filled, forState: UIControlState.Disabled);
```

Second I made a function, this function change state of your button.

```
selectButton(button:UIButton)
{
    option1Button.enabled = button != option1Button;
    option2Button.enabled = button != option2Button;
}
```

Now you just do implement this way you action, and other detail is you don't need more create a function for every button ex. `@IBAction func option1ButtonAction(sender: AnyObject)` only create one action `@IBAction func onButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject)` and like all buttons here... remember only increment your buttons in your `selectButton(button:UIButton)` function, or if preferrer you can create a collection and push your button there and do a while in `selectButton`

```
@IBAction func onButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let clickedButton = sender as? UIButton{
        selectButton(clickedButton);
    }

}
```

If I understood correctly your issue, I hope helped you!